# Update d3 graph from dynamic JSON (onStateChange)

Tags: json, d3.js, vaadin, force-layout

I am working with the Vaadin framework (https://vaadin.com/home) integrating d3.js to my java code (analogous to http://www.rapidpm.org/2013/10/using-javascript-libraries-d3-in-vaadin.html). Basically, this Javascript code is bound to a Java class and reacts to a change of state in said Java class.

==================================================================================

So, when the state of the java diagram-class changes, this.conStateChange-method is called: javascript fetches a new String from the java class (var string = this.getState().string;), parses it to JSON and renders a graph.

A button click will trigger the state change by changing the String in the java class (!), thereby triggering the described method and rendering the new graph from the new JSON-parsed-String.

...THEORETICALLY... however, in reality, if I click that button once the graph disappears. Only if I click the button again, the new graph is rendered.

```
/*not so interesting code
var diagramElement = this.getElement();
var width = 960, height = 500;
var force = d3.layout.force().size([ width, height ])
            .charge(-400)
            .linkDistance(40)
            .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
            .on("dragstart", dragstart);

var svg = d3.select(diagramElement)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"), 
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");*/

/*interesting code*/
this.onStateChange = function() {

    link.remove(); //delete old graph
    node.remove(); //delete old graph

    var string = this.getState().string;
    graph = JSON.parse(string);

    force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();

    link = link.data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link");
    node = node.data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 12)
            .on("dblclick", dblclick)
            .call(drag);
};
```

So whats wrong with this (indeed not very elegant) code, and how can I achieve that a single click will [1] remove the graph displayed and [2] render a new graph?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: any errors in the browser console?  can you add some console.log lines in your JS code to see, if everything is ok with the data?  e.g. ``console.log(string); var graph = JSON.parse(string); console.log(graph);``

Comment: I have added your console outputs in the onStateChange function. They're output is always the same, when loading, when clicking the button once or twice... console.log(string) ==> " Object { nodes=[13], links=[18]} "

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have found a solution and I'm still a noob in d3 but I would like to suggest as this solution helped me. However, my force layout derived its data from a csv and not JSON not sure if it makes much difference.

I included " graph = { "nodes": [], "links": [] }; " in the "this.onStateChange = function() {" as this will help fill up the arrays with new data. Hope it helps!